# vector mesons identified with positive parity

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, parity, textbook-erratum, mesons, hadron-dynamics

I have seen in some sources (like in https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06090, page 11, footnote 11 but also in some few more) that vector mesons are assigned with positive parity $(J^P)=1^+$. In Particle Data Booklet it is written (and in general) that vector mesons are $1^-$ not $1^+$.

So, what is the difference here? is it just a typo or am I missing something? The reason I did not think it was a typo because pseudoscalars are given with correct quantum numbers $0^-$ where axial vector-mesons are given with $1^-$ (opposite sign with respect to vector mesons and wrong w.r.t. PDG again).

Comment: Looks like a typo. PDG controls.